# envsubst with ogr2ogr external .sql file

Tags: bash, sqlite, terminal, gdal, ogr2ogr

I’m trying to combine the envsubst command with an external sql file passed as an option to ogr2ogr, but can't quite get it work.

```
export STOP_NAME=Park;

ogr2ogr \
-f geojson \
/vsistdout/ \
stops.csv \
-dialect sqlite \
-sql envsubst < @stop_geo.sql
```

Where stop_geo.sql is:

```
SELECT *
FROM stops
WHERE stop_name = '$STOP_NAME'
```

This errors out with:

```
Warning 1: layer names ignored in combination with -sql.
ERROR 1: In ExecuteSQL(): sqlite3_prepare_v2(envsubst):
  near "envsubst": syntax error
```

Is there any way to replace the environment variable in the external sql file within the ogr2ogr -sql command option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The envsubst command needs to be wrapped in a quoted command substitution (i.e., "$()"). Instead of using the @ syntax as mentioned in the [ogr2ogr sql documentation](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html#cmdoption-ogr2ogr-sql), it simply needs to be read in using the common < operator.

```
export STOP_NAME=Park;

ogr2ogr \
-f geojson \
/vsistdout/ \
stops.csv \
-dialect sqlite \
-sql "$(envsubst < stop_geo.sql)"
```